# Nested Iframe is not accessible in Watin

Tags: iframe, watin

I am trying to Automate a web application using Watin.

I have HTMLDialog Popup, When i click on an Icon in the HTMLDialog Popup the iframe refresh and the HTML Content would Look some thing like this.

```
<html>
<body>
<Form> </form>
<iframe Name = "A">
 <html>
  <Body>
   <Form Name="frmMain">
    <Table Name ="tblMain">
     <Tbody>
      <TR>  
        <TD>
          <iframe Name = "B">
            <Html>
              <Body>
                <frame Name="innerForm">
                 <Table>
                   <Div> My Object </Div>
                 </Table> ...
```

I am not able to identify elements inside the iFrame 'B', the InnerHtml for the iframe'B' is always null.

Code Used to get the Inner HTML:

```
Browser.Frame(Find.ByName("A")).Form(Find.ByName("frmMain")).Table(Find.ById("tblMain")).TableBodies[0].TableRows[0].ElementWithTag("iframe", Find.ById("B")).InnerHtml;
```

I could see the iFrame 'B' contain the item i want to select using IE 'Developer Tool'.

Am i missing something, since i want to select a item inside the iFrame 'B'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I remember well frames are found in the `Browser` element, and you should access an `iframe` as a normal frame. I can't access my source to verify, but I suggest you to try

```
Browser.Frame(Find.ByName("A")).Frame(Find.ById("B"))
```

to access your required frame.

Comment: Thanks Gabber, tried Browser.Frame(Find.ByName("A")).Frame(Find.ById("B")) and this worked..!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I edited the question to match the correct solution for the future